# Dr.Memory can't find line number of reachable leaks

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, dr-memory

I'm debugging with Dr.Memory and somehow it doesn't show line number of where the leak is. Is there anyway to see it or solve this problem? I'm using c and this is what -showreachable gave me. I also tried doing -Werror -g but that didn't find the line number as well. I've only made 3 new matrixes with malloc and I freed them all so it's really weird that there is 6 leaks.

```
~~Dr.M~~ Error #1: REACHABLE LEAK 4096 direct bytes 0x00000001033e22c0-0x00000001033e32c0 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ <memory was allocated before tool took control>
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ Error #2: REACHABLE LEAK 4096 direct bytes 0x00000001033e32e0-0x00000001033e42e0 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ <memory was allocated before tool took control>
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ Error #3: REACHABLE LEAK 513 direct bytes 0x00000001033e5460-0x00000001033e5661 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ <memory was allocated before tool took control>
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ Error #4: REACHABLE LEAK 80 direct bytes 0x00000001033e5910-0x00000001033e5960 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ <memory was allocated before tool took control>
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ Error #5: REACHABLE LEAK 36 direct bytes 0x00000001033e5980-0x00000001033e59a4 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ <memory was allocated before tool took control>
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ Error #6: REACHABLE LEAK 32 direct bytes 0x00000001033e59d0-0x00000001033e59f0 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ <memory was allocated before tool took control>
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ ERRORS FOUND:
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~       6 unique,     6 total,   8853 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
~~Dr.M~~ NO ERRORS IGNORED
```

Comment: Compile and link with the debug flag — usually `-g`.

Comment: It's not leaked memory if it's still reachable... (Whether it should be freed at some point when you're done with it, or if it's okay to leave it till the program exits, now, that's another story)

Comment: Note that the messages say that the memory was allocated before the tool got control. That probably means it is allocated in the startup code before `main()` is called. There’s nothing you can do about such leaks except, perhaps, ignore them.

Comment: Thank you, I sent it to my friends and it seems like it works on their dr.memory without error message. So I guess it's really a Dr.memory problem